# Disable btn-group On Click in dropdown-menu Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to pass some checkboxes in Bootstrap button Group and ONLY hide the associated `.dropdown-menu` when the `#apply` clicked.

As you can see in [This Demo](http://www.bootply.com/l0rrEIJada) clicks on `list-group-item`s hides the `.dropdown-menu` unless you exactly click on checkboxes

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu list-group">
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="type" value="item1"> Item 1 </button>
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="type" value="item2"> Item 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="type" value="item3"> Item 3</button>
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="type" value="item4"> Item 4</button>
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item"><input class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit" value="Apply Changes" id="apply"></button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you please let me know how I can prevent this and also enable the `#apply` button to correctly close the `dropdown-menu` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is something :

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/YxjE9W947H)**

**JS**:

```
$("#apply").on("click", function(){
  $("input:checked").parent().hide().slideUp();
});

$('.list-group-item').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```